# HTML/PHP - Undefined Indexes

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. Made a simple two input form, the goal is to store both inputs into a text file. For some reason the code throws out two Undefined Index notices and nothing gets added into the text file, any help? Thanks in advance.

```
<form method=”post” action="formsaver.php">

                <input name="email" placeholder="Your Email"></input><br>
                <input name="jobdesc" id="jobdesc" placeholder="Message (255 Char Max)" maxlength="255"></input><br>
            <button id="landpgbutton" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="success();">Let's Talk</button>


</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $jobdesc = $_POST["jobdesc"];
    $s = $email . "," . $jobdesc . "/n";
    $fileLoc = "./dataset.txt";
    file_put_contents($fileLoc, $s);
```

?>

Comment: Firstly - your `input`'s are invalid HTML. They are self closing meaning they do not require `</input>`.

Comment: Generally it's good practice to check if an index is set by using `isset()`. In this case make sure the index exists with `isset($_POST["email"])` and `isset($_POST["jobdesc"])`.

Comment: Secondly - have you tried to echo the `$email` and `$jobdesc` variables to see if you're receiving the data as expected? Those two variables are likely not being filled hence the undefined indexes

Comment: The quotes in `method=”post”` are invalid. Should be `"` instead of `”`

Comment: Thanks everyone! TiiJ7's solution fixed it, also thank you for the extra tips everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid quotes.
You currently have:

```
method=”post” (Invalid)
```

It should be:

```
method="post"
```

or:

```
method='post'
```

If you're unsure if the index is set or not, you could use the function `isset(): bool` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

This will determine if the variable is set and isn't null (In this case, you could see if an index is set).

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Hope this helps and good luck!